# Any idea what's causing kernel panic on iMac 2017?

Tags: imac, crash, kernel-panic

It is iMac 2017.

Crash dumps https://gist.github.com/morr/88c22be99fe9d2b014964ada3a46d6a4

1. It started to happen on Big Sur with all latest updates. Just crashes in 1) random moments 2) after some time when I put iMac to sleep.
2. I upgraded to Monterey but still got crashes.
3. I erased hard drive and installed Monterey. In 15 min after reinstall I got crash again (XCode were installing at that point, no additional software were installed)

Now I keep getting crashes in 1) random moments 2) after some time when I put imac to sleep

I detached all external devices from iMac - it did not help
I reset SMC and PRAM - it did not help

Any ideas other than sending iMac to Apple?

Comment: Only one iMac 2017 has user accessible RAM. If you have a Retina 5K, 27" iMac: iMac18,3 Model Number A1419, you might want to unseat and reseat the RAM (very carefully) using the [instructions here](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201191).

Comment: Strongly agree with IconDaemon on reseating RAM. Other basic debugging techniques are to (1) turn off AirPort and Bluetooth, and (2) boot into Safe Mode (hold Shift during boot). If you do both of those, does the problem remain or go away? (My suspicion, from observing the pattern in the machine check registers in your crash reports, is that this is a hardware failure, but SW issues can also manifest as machine check exceptions so we should try to isolate first.)

Comment: My searching indicates that your iMac18,3 shipped with a Fusion drive. If you've never replaced the hard drive(s), it's possible the spinning disk part of the Fusion drive is failing and needs replacement with an SSD.

Comment: @jasonology While you’re right about the 5-year point being a reasonable rule-of-thumb for rotational storage failures, the pattern of crash signatures here doesn’t suggest that that’s what’s happening. With platter data corruption one would typically see kernel panics inside random or IO-bound stack frames, not MCA bank 0 exceptions with identical statuses and localized addresses.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for helpful answers! I tried all suggested methods of fixing/diagnostics except of replacing SSD. I also tried to remove memory planks and to install each one separately and tried to install planks into different slots. Nothing helped, unfortunately, but at the end I was able to reproduce kernel panic steadily. I get black screen of death in 5-300 seconds almost ("almost" because sometimes it do not reboot immediately and continue playing video for a long time) every time when I open trackpad/mouse osx application on a tab which plays video https://apple.co/37bEYe0

Comment: I think I was wrong and there is no correlation. It keeps crashing even with no applications started and no devices attached.

Comment: Have you run Apple Diagnostics? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731

Comment: @pion I did. It found no issues.